# Datadog Display External Data Source in Dashboard

Tags: datadog

I want to display a simple data table that I have stored in an AWS S3 bucket in .CSV format in a Datadog dashboard that I have created. Is that possible? If so, how do I get Datadog to reach that data and then, visualise it on my dashboard using its widgets, such as a Table or a Query Value.